# Is there a way to skip the installation of few packages which are define in Makefile?

Tags: makefile

I am trying to skip installation of few packages which are define in Makefile while running `make package` command . I cannot change makefile so want to just skip those steps in any other way.
I am installing those packages locally and copy them to the path by using dockerfile.

When I tried to run `make package` it gave me an error:

```
cannot create directory '/usr/local/bin/codechecker/tools/plist_to_html/plist_to_html/static/vendor/codemirror': File exists
```

I also tried to use `make package -k` but it also failed with error because of earlier errors:

```
#17 17.61 make: Target 'package' not remade because of errors.
```

Is there a way to avoid these error and skip the steps from makefile? would appreciate any help.

Comment: Could you provide a bit more context as to what you're trying to do, in what environment ? Why can you not change the Makefile ? Anyway it looks like you have some files that were already created, so you could try to remove them (or rather back them up) and see if that helps.

Comment: The root cause seems to be a `mkdir` call that should be `mkdir -p`. Check if your makefile has a `DESTDIR` argument to redirect stuff to.

Comment: please show a [mre]

Comment: I am trying codechecker make-package from dockerfile to build an image , make package work fine but take a lot of time with few i.e codemirror  packages , so i tried to COPY those packages from local to the required path in the container . that is why its getting already exist error.

Comment: I want to get rid of those error and say if that directory is already exist then skip and should not give error .. not really sure if its possible or not ?

Comment: Also , in make file they have "mkdir -p $ $(CODEMIRROR_DIR)" already , i feel it should skip the error when using -p . but seems not skipping the error.